# Center align legend text and circle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to draw a horizontal legend for my graph, but not sure how I can center align it as well as keeping it on same distance from one an other.
[image]

I can draw the group for each item containing

```
<g class="legend">
    <g class="item">
        <circle r="2" ... />
        <text>passed</text>
    </g>
    ...
</g>
```

as the text is of dynamic width how I can position it so it has same distance i.e. red lines
and the whole g.legend at the center of the svg i.e the blue lines.

...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.legend{ /* Container (You can use text-align: center instead of flex in you want) */
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.legend::before{ /* The line */
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  left: 0;
  top: calc( 1rem + 2px ); /* Line height + Border thickness */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.legend div{ /* Each legend item */
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend">
  <div>• Legend 1</div>
  <div>• Legend 2</div>
  <div>• Legend 3</div>
</div>
```

You can make use of the CSS `::before` pseudo-selector to achieve this. Please comment if you have any queries. I cant

Comment: use the <foreignObject> element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject to embed HTML into your SVG and just center the HTML via CSS.